# python install speex dsp module error

Tags: python, speex

I would like to ask a question about the installing `speexdsp` module in python installed with `Anaconda3`.

I downloaded the `swigwin-3.0.12` from website and add it to my system variable, as well as my `python35.lib` and the `python\include`. However, I get the following message:

```
cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

From my research, it looks like this could be solved by adding it to system variable, but doing that didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu thn use this command.

> sudo apt-get install build-essential libspeex-dev libspeexdsp-dev
>   libpulse-dev

On mac (homebrew)

> brew install speex speexdsp

[Speexdsp git](https://github.com/xiph/speexdsp)

[Speex official website](https://www.speex.org)

Get info from their official website.